# Moving from a vector with one allocator to a vector with another

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I've got a `vector<T, alloc>` where `alloc` is a simple wrapper on `std::allocator<T>` that performs some additional bookkeeping, like counting the number of created objects and such.

Now I want to move from my `vector<T, alloc>` into `vector<T>`. None of the vector move functions seems to accept `vector`s with different allocators.

How can I move data from one vector to another where the allocators are not the same?

Comment: I think what you are asking for makes total sense but unfortunately vector is defined/implemented in a way that doesn't allow this. I think it is currently not possible but it should be. The only option I can think of is some kind of specilization of vector for the special allocator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John Zwinck explains in his answer, you can not move the vector. However, you can move the elements of the vector as follows:

```
vector<...> u;
...
vector<...> v(
    std::make_move_iterator(u.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(u.end())
);
```

or

```
vector<...> u;
vector<...> v;
...
v.insert(
    v.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(u.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(u.end())
);
```

or (suggested by Oktalist)

```
vector<...> u;
vector<...> v;
...
std::move(u.begin(), u.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: This is a good point, though the way I understood the question was about a desire to move the vector data from one to the other.  For example, if you have a huge vector of integers you might want to avoid copying them, which `move_iterator` doesn't seem to help with.  I guess it depends on whether the original reason for the question came from a large vector of small objects or the other way around.

Comment: @John Zwinck I agree. That is not quite what the OP wants, but maybe the best one can do.

Comment: `std::move(u.begin(), u.end(), std::back_inserter(v));` as an alternative in the second case.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a weird thing about the STL.  You will need to `insert()` the values of your source vector into  your destination vector.  Or you can use one of the several alternate-universe STL implementations which address this issue directly, for example:

- The Bloomberg Basic Development Environment (BDE) STL has a runtime polymorphic allocator described here: https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/wiki/BDE-Allocator-model .  It's open source at the same site.
- The Electronic Arts STL, described here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html with source online here: https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL

Some of the folks who made the above quasi-STL implementations tried to get their allocator model changes adopted into the C++ standard, but they were not successful.

Comment: I can't `insert()` them because there's not enough exception safety guarantees in erasing the source vector and then inserting the new elements.

Comment: What is your T?  Maybe you can consider the other answer here using `move_iterator` if your T is movable, or swap from source to dest, or maybe even rethink why you need a custom allocator in the first place (you can get memory allocation metrics other ways on some platforms).